# Create new variable in R with assumptions from SPSS file

Tags: r, spss, recode

I've read in my SPSS file in R and want to recode a new variable if such and such assumptions are made. To be specific:

I want to turn my `spssdata_sub$gest` variable into a new variable if the following the conditions are met:

```
spssdata_sub$indusert != 2 & spssdata_sub$ivf != 1 & spssdata_sub$leie != 3 & spssdata_sub$svkompl_II != 7 & spssdata_sub$svkompl_II != 2 & spssdata_sub$svkompl_II != 1
```

Anyone here who can help me with a code?

Comment: `spssdata_sub$gest  <- ifelse(spssdata_sub$indusert != 2 & spssdata_sub$ivf != 1 & spssdata_sub$leie != 3 & spssdata_sub$svkompl_II != 7 & spssdata_sub$svkompl_II != 2 & spssdata_sub$svkompl_II != 1, newvalue, spssdata_sub$gest)`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this code. If I run this I just get a new variable with NA values. Sorry, I'm pretty new to R, and trying to learn!

Comment: Can you maybe provide a reproducible example (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for instructions)?

Comment: And maybe an addition to the comment of @Renu: You have to change *newvalue* to an actual value.

Comment: Thanks, what I want is the values of spssdata_sub$gest  to be the same, but if 
spssdata_sub$indusert != 2 & spssdata_sub$ivf != 1 & spssdata_sub$leie != 3 & spssdata_sub$svkompl_II != 7 & spssdata_sub$svkompl_II != 2 & spssdata_sub$svkompl_II != 1
Then I want them left out of the new variable

Comment: To clarify it should be or not &. I dont want it in the new variable if any of criteria are met.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure whether I understand you correctly, but `ifelse()` works as follows: `ifelse(condition, yes, no)`, with `yes` meaning (i.e., returning) the value if the condition is met and `no` meaning the value if the condition isn't met.

Comment: What I'm looking to do is to exclude individuals which has either of the following from my dataset. if either 
spssdata_sub$indusert = 2
 spssdata_sub$ivf = 1 
spssdata_sub$leie = 3 
 spssdata_sub$svkompl_II = 7 
spssdata_sub$svkompl_II = 2 
spssdata_sub$svkompl_II = 1

Then I want all thouse individuals out. I only want to have spssdata_sub$gest for individuals which has none of these..

Answer (score 0):

Does one of the following codes work for you?

Either this adapted version of Renu's solution

```
spssdata_sub$gest <- ifelse(spssdata_sub$indusert != 2 & spssdata_sub$ivf != 1 & spssdata_sub$leie != 3 & spssdata_sub$svkompl_II != 7 & spssdata_sub$svkompl_II != 2 & spssdata_sub$svkompl_II != 1, spssdata_sub$gest, NA)
```

or this code for filtering observations:

```
library(dplyr)
spssdata_sub_new <- spssdata_sub %>% 
filter(indusert != 2 & ivf != 1 & leie != 3 & svkompl_II != 7 & svkompl_II != 2 & ssvkompl_II != 1)
```

Comment: No, the first one only return a list of NA, I think a problem there might be that it is saying and to all the criteria? I need an OR criteria, as individuals dont need to have more than one to be excluded. I've tried | insted of &, but that does not help.
On #2 I just get an error.

Comment: If it's OR then it should be `|` instead of `&`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is the following, if you really mean either one of the conditions

```
Mynewdata <- dplyr::filter(spssdata, indusert != 2, ivf != 1, leie != 3,
             svkompl_II != 7 & svkompl_II != 2 & svkompl_II != 1)
```

only keeps entries that are neither, or putting it the other way exludes entries that have either indusert = 2 or ivf = 1 etc... one of the condition is enough to exclude it.

**add-on**: or something also like that:

```
Mynewdata <- dplyr::filter(spssdata, indusert != 2, ivf != 1, leie != 3,
             !(svkompl_II %in% c(7,2,1))
```